# Как изменить цвет текста FindDialog?

Tags: java, android

Возникла небольшая проблемка с `ShowFindDialog` для `WebView`. Нигде не могу найти никакой информации на счет изменения цвета заднего фона либо цвета текста в нем:

```
webView.showFindDialog(null, true);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Может ли кто либо, пожалуйста, подсказать, как все же кастомизировать данный элемент под свои нужды? Заранее большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]